# Search a file (simple grep clone)

Tags: algorithm, c, file, reinventing-the-wheel, homework

For part of a project, I was given this directive:

> The grep command will take an exact string and an exact filename as
>   the 2 arguments and you will need to search through the filename for
>   the given string and display the "line" and "line number" the string
>   resides in.
>   Example output would be:
>
> ```
> # grep bob FileWithBob
> 12 and then bob picked up the phone and called jane 
> 24 even though they knew that bobby was not going to show up
> ```

Testing seems to give identical results to the actual grep program for everything I've tried:

```
$ ./my_grep "test" grep.c 
1:// test
2:// multi-line test

$ grep -n "test" grep.c 
1:// test
2:// multi-line test
```

**grep.c**:

```
// test
// multi-line test
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1       // for getline()
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifndef streq
#define streq(x, y) (strcmp((x), (y)) == 0)
#endif

#define MSGBUFSIZE  512

regex_t pattern;

int compile_pattern(const char *pat)
{
    int flags = REG_NOSUB;
    char error[MSGBUFSIZE] = "";

    int ret = regcomp(&pattern, pat, flags);
    if (ret)
    {
        regerror(ret, &pattern, error, sizeof(error));
        fprintf(stderr, "pattern `%s`: %s\n", pat, error);
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

// read lines of text and match against the pattern
int process(FILE *fp)
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    char error[MSGBUFSIZE] = "";
    int ret = 0;

    for (int i = 1; getline(&buf, &size, fp) != -1; i++)
    {
        ret = regexec(&pattern, buf, 0, NULL, 0);
        if (ret)
        {
            if (ret != REG_NOMATCH)
            {
                regerror(ret, &pattern, error, sizeof(error));
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
                free(buf);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        else
            printf("%d:%s", i, buf);
    }

    free(buf);
    return 0;
}

void usage(char* prog_name)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-i] [-E] pattern [ files ... ]\n", prog_name);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (1 == argc)
        usage(argv[0]);

    int err = compile_pattern(argv[optind]);
    if (err)
        return err;
    else
        optind++;

    if (optind == argc) // no files, default to stdin
        process(stdin);
    else {
        for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        {
            if (streq(argv[i], "-"))
                process(stdin);
            else if ((fp = fopen(argv[i], "r")))
            {
                process(fp);
                fclose(fp);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: could not open: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
                err = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    regfree(&pattern);
    return err;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the whole your code seems pretty concise and clean.  I've just got a couple of side points.

**Scope creep**

This is a real problem in production code, where developers implement stuff that isn't really needed.  Your specification you've posted says 'take an exact string and an exact filename'.  You've allowed a regular expression to be passed.  The original requirements could have been met by just using `strstr` which would have made the code quite a bit smaller.  You've used extra time and added extra complexity, is there a real benefit?

The scope creep also means that I can't pass the basic string "\n" into your parser and have it find it as the '\n' is interpretted by the regex parser.  So, with grep I can do:

> grep -F "\n" someFile.h

And get lines with the text \n:

> printf("some text\n");

Whereas running your code:

> ./a.exe "\n" someFile.h

I get every line that ends in a newline (i.e. every line of the file).

**-h -i and arguments**

If you're going to implement programs that take in arguments, it's a good idea to give the user some way to find out what the arguments mean.  When I use `grep -i`, I'm trying to do a case-insensitive search.  Your program advertises a '-i' option, however it doesn't do the same thing as grep.  Instead I get told it can't open a file:

> $ ./a.exe -i if someFile.h
>
> if: could not open: No such file or directory